# How to find the surface of integration

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The problem gives the curl of a vector field, and tells us to calculate the line integral over $C$ where $C$ is the intersection of $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $z= y^2$. I know I should use Stokes Theorem, but how do I find $dS$?

I did $z = \frac{1}{2}(y^2 + 1 - x^2)$ and calculated $dS$ as $\langle-dz/dx,-dz/dy,1\rangle$ but apparently that was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I drew a figure illustrating how these two surfaces intersecting with each other[image: .]

The intersecting curve $C$ is that black line, and let's assume $C$'s direction is rotating counter-clockwise if you look from above. The surface $S$ is part of the $z=y^2$ that is inside the cylinder. Its surface normal is taking gradient of the equation $y^2 - z= 0$: $(0,2y,-1)$, normalize it we have the unit vector normal is $\mathbf{n} = (0,2y,-1)/\sqrt{4y^2+1}$

Suppose the vector field given is $\mathbf{F}$, then by Stokes theorem:
$$
\oint_C \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r} = \int_S \nabla \times \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S} = \int_S \nabla \times \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n}\,dS,
$$
where the $\mathbf{n}\,dS$ part is probably what you are looking for. Then what you need to do is just parametrizing $S$, and compute [a surface integral for a scalar field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral).

Answer (score 0):

So long as there isn't any sort of problem point (such as if the vector field you're integrating is undefined at the origin), you can integrate over any surface that is closed within the definition. So let $z=y^2$ be the surface, and let $x^2+y^2=1$ describe the limits of the surface (because $x^2+y^2=1$ doesn't form a simple surface).

If you convert to cylindrical coordinates, then $z=y^2=r^2\sin^2\theta$ is the surface and the bound is given by $r\leq 1$, $0\leq \theta< 2\pi$. So
$$\mathbf{r}=x\mathbf{i}+y\mathbf{j}+y^2\mathbf{k}$$ and $$d\mathbf{S}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial x}\times\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial y}dxdy=\mathbf{i}\times\left(\mathbf{j}+2y\mathbf{k}\right)dxdy=\left(\mathbf{k}-2y\mathbf{j}\right)dxdy$$ and since $$dxdy=rdrd\theta$$ we have
$$
d\mathbf{S}=(\mathbf{k}-2r\sin\theta\mathbf{j})rdrd\theta
$$